# External monitor not working on full resolution with MacBook

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

I know this problem has been answered before, but I could not make any of the presented solutions work for me.

I just bought a Phillips 245B monitor with QHD (2560x1440) so I could run it in native resolution with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) and its NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M GPU.

Unfortunately the maximum resolution that IOS lets me choose is 1080p.

I tried already:

1. Preferences -> Displays -> option-click on Scaled
2. Resetting the PRAM
3. A different Mini Display Port to HDMI adapter (from Gravis) and a Mini Display Port to display port adapter, which resulted in a "no video output" on the monitor.
4. Creating a new EDID file like [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221498/354556), which resulted in the monitor staying black.

I hope one of you guys can help me :-)

Cheers

Comment: [Don't use HDMI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271).  Use the DisplayPort connection.  It's more than likely you're using an older HDMI cable, or a passive adapter; maybe both.  If you go DP, you don't convert the signal which means things are more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But as I said above I already tried a Mini Display Port to display port adapter, which resulted in a "no video output" on the monitor...

Comment: Then there may be an issue with your monitor.  The signal that comes out of the Mac is DP.  Then it's converted to HDMI (with your cable).  If you're having issues on both ports of the monitor, your next step would be to try it on a known working computer (both ports)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The monitor is definitely OK. With a different (windows) computer (directly via HDMI) it works fine on full resolution. I also checked my computer on other monitors and via Display Port I have the same problem, that no connection is established. What I could not try if I can transfer QHD resolution via HDMI to a different monitor, but since Display Port is not working on these other monitors either the overall problem seems to be similar.