# External monitor not working with Mini Display Port to Display Port adapter or cable

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, resolution

I just bought a Phillips 245B monitor with QHD (2560x1440) so I could run it in native resolution with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) and its NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M GPU.

Unfortunately with a Mini Display Port to Display Port adapter or cable the Mac does not recognize that there is a external monitor and the monitor just outputs "no video output".

With an Mini Display Port to HDMI adapter or cable the monitor works but with a maximum resolution of 1080p.

I tried already:

1. Preferences -> Displays -> option-click on Scaled
2. Resetting the PRAM
3. Different Mini Display Port to HDMI adapters and a Mini Display Port to HDMI cable without adapter.
4. A Mini Display Port to Display Port adapter and a Mini Display Port to Display Port cable, which resulted in the "no video output" on the monitor.
5. Creating a new EDID file like [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221498/354556), which resulted in the monitor staying black.

What I did not try yet is an active Mini Display Port to HDMI adapter because no shop has one and also because I guess that if Mini Display Port to Display Port does not work there is a different problem.

I hope one of you guys can help me, I just do not know what else I can do...

Cheers

Comment: Would not you need a mini displayport to dual link DVI adaptor?

Comment: From my understanding DVI would just be another yet older possibility next to Display Port and HDMI!?