# Unable to copy a file to '/System/' path (MacOS BigSur)

Tags: macos

I recently updated my MacBook Pro to BigSur. Although it is running fine, it is not recognising my external display properly (just like in any previous MacOS release). Long back I had got solution which is explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221239/my-external-monitor-doesnt-work-at-full-resolution-with-my-macbook). In order to do that, I need to override the display settings by copying a file to `/System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/`

But my problem is I am unable to copy the file to the above directory as it is read-only.

The steps I followed,

- I disabled the SIP by booting into recovery
- I rebooted my MacBook Pro

And I am on my *admin* account.

When I was in my MacOS Catelina, I was able to copy that file to above location.

Comment: I ran across this online and found (a different) article about that. TD;LR SIP has *changed* and you need to do more https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/

Comment: Thanks Steve. I went through the article you have shared. To be frank, I do not know that much deep in MacOS operating system.
What I understood is, it very hard to to make any changes to the system volume as now everything is SHA hashed!

Comment: Hi again Steve, 
I solved my issue by copying it to /Library/... folder as explained in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649832

Answer (score 0):

- Get the correct EDID data (see [My external monitor doesn't work at full resolution with my MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221239/my-external-monitor-doesnt-work-at-full-resolution-with-my-macbook))
- Copy overrides to `/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-*` (taken from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649832))

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link which doesn’t even link. Can you please summarize the linked page in your answer so it stands on its own?

Comment: Sure. I have added the links and some information which could help someone